# Don't accept RDNSS from router announcements in Linux

Tags: linux, linux-networking, router, ipv6

I have an Ubuntu 20.04 router that uses its own IP as DNS server obtained from router announcements, creating DNS loops. I can't figure out how to ignore RDNSS (recursive DNS server) from router announcements.

Loop:

```
Jan 19 17:26:28 myrouter dnsmasq[1074014]: query[AAAA] mobile.events.data.trafficmanager.net from fe80::21b:21ff:fee0:a6b3
Jan 19 17:26:28 myrouter dnsmasq[1074014]: forwarded mobile.events.data.trafficmanager.net to 127.0.0.53
Jan 19 17:26:28 myrouter dnsmasq[1074014]: query[AAAA] mobile.events.data.trafficmanager.net from fe80::21b:21ff:fee0:a6b3
Jan 19 17:26:28 myrouter dnsmasq[1074014]: forwarded mobile.events.data.trafficmanager.net to 127.0.0.53
```

Network setup:

- eth0 = not used.
- eth1 = WAN. `99.99.99.162/24`, `2a01:xx:xx:xx::2/126`
- eth2 = LAN1. `10.50.0.1/16`, `2a01:xx:xx:1337:10:50:0:1/64`
- more LANs, not relevant

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth1:
      match:
        macaddress: "00:1b:21:e0:a6:b2" <-- non-obfuscated
      set-name: eth1
      addresses:
        - 99.99.99.162/24
        - 2a01:xx:xx:xx::2/126
      gateway4: 99.99.99.161
      gateway6: 2a01:xx:xx:xx::1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 33.33.33.10
          - 44.44.44.10
        search: [ company, company.nl ]
    eth2:
      match:
        macaddress: "00:1b:21:e0:a6:b3" <-- non-obfuscated; will appear as IPv6 fe80
      set-name: eth2
      addresses:
        - 10.50.0.1/16
        - 2a01:xx:xx:1337:10:50:0:1/64
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 33.33.33.10
          - 44.44.44.10
```

Dnsmasq binds on all except `eth1` and `lo`. `Radvdump` shows that after restart of `dnsmasq`, it sends out a router advertisement with `fe80::21b:21ff:fee0:a6b3` as RDNSS (recursive DNS server). Our clients don't seem to pick it up, and only use the IPv4 one. But, the router itself does:

```
Link 5 (eth2)
      Current Scopes: DNS                     
DefaultRoute setting: yes                     
       LLMNR setting: yes                     
MulticastDNS setting: no                      
  DNSOverTLS setting: no                      
      DNSSEC setting: no                      
    DNSSEC supported: no                      
  Current DNS Server: 33.33.33.10           
         DNS Servers: 44.44.44.10             
                      33.33.33.10           
                      fe80::21b:21ff:fee0:a6b3 <- appears a short while after 'netplan try'
```

I tried disabling it:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra = 0
net.ipv6.conf.lo.accept_ra = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_ra = 0
```

But no luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the kernel's job to update nameservers based on RDNSS. It's done via whatever you use to manage your network connections.

**edit**
Misunderstood what you wanted, thought of a way too complicated scenario.
Rephrasing it slightly: "Having a static ipv4 and v6 setup, netplan does SLAAC anyway. Why?"

To fix this, include

```
accept-ra: false
```

in your netplan config for the desired interface(s), [source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1004509/slaac-wont-disable-on-ubuntu-17-10).

For completeness sake, here's a sample config for a freshly provisioned Ubuntu 20.10 box:

```
network:
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
      accept-ra: false
      addresses:
        - 192.168.1.x/24
        - 2001:DB8::64/64
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      gateway6: 2001:DB8::1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 192.168.1.1
  version: 2
```

The following was "I want SLAAC, but without RDNSS!":

In Ubuntu's case, it's managed with netplan. When testing it, I was unable to use SLAAC without RDNSS. I suggest setting your IPv6 address statically.

Here's from `netplan`'s [manpage](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/5-netplan/):

> dhcp6 (bool)
>
> Enable DHCP for IPv6. Off by default. This covers both stateless DHCP - where the DHCP server supplies information like DNS nameservers but not the IP address - and stateful DHCP, where the server provides both the address and the other information.
>
> If you are in an IPv6-only environment with completely stateless autoconfiguration (SLAAC with RDNSS), this option can be set to cause the interface to be brought up. (Setting accept-ra alone is not sufficient.) Autoconfiguration will still honour the contents of the router advertisement and only use DHCP if requested in the RA.
>
> Note that rdnssd(8) is required to use RDNSS with networkd. No extra software is required for NetworkManager.
>
> [...]
>
> If both dhcp4 and dhcp6 are true, the networkd backend requires that dhcp4-overrides and dhcp6-overrides contain the same keys and values. If the values do not match, an error will be shown and the network configuration will not be applied.

Comment: All network configuration on that machine is static, with Netplan.

Comment: Sorry mate, I misunderstood. Please check if I got it right this time :-)

Comment: Wow. Arcane, but so far it works. After a few minutes, that nameserver hasn't reappeared yet. I'll await it bit more and accept your answer. I can't say I understand it though. `rdnssd` is not installed or running. Nor is NetworkManager. That is in conflict with that man page.